# Is there a homomorphic mapping between natural language and logic

Tags: logic

To me, this might be possible with a very complicated logic but then there should be no calculi that are useful. And is there an algorithm for it that could do that? This already looks very undecidable.

Comment: Maybe with [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard Montague tried something along these lines in the 1970s. Here is a quote from his "[Universal Grammar](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1755-2567.1970.tb00434.x)", *Theoria*, 36: 373–398, 1970:

> There is in my opinion no important theoretical difference between natural languages and the artificial languages of logicians; indeed I consider it possible to comprehend the syntax and semantics of both kinds of languages with a single natural and mathematically precise theory.

See, for instance, the entry on [Montague Semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/montague-semantics/) in the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*.

More broadly, the field of formal semantics (which Montague helped found) is dedicated to understanding and modelling natural language with the tools of logic and computer science.

A full mapping of natural language into formal logic is still a pipe dream, however. People are still debating how to understand quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that does not exist, because natural language is inconsistent, has many definitions for the same words, connotations as well as denotations that vary with the speaker and the listener, and in general is nothing like logic.  Any language that has puns and poetry is not going to be describable with logic.